# Pandas groupby using MultiIndex values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

Suppose I have a dataframe  with multiindex columns representing student majors and student GPAs.  I want to find the class rank per major for each row.  If the students had only one major each, then I could stack the major as another level of the multiindex and groupby(level=1).rank().  However, because the students can change their major, I have to have those as a separate feature for each year.  What would be an efficient way to get the correct output?  I know I could brute force it by iterating over the rows, but I'm hoping to avoid that as I may be dealing with a large amount of data.

Sample df:

```
categories = ['major', 'gpa']
students = ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Sara']
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([categories, students])
index = range(4)
students_df = pd.DataFrame([['english', 'math', 'math', 3.8, 2.2, 3.7],
                            ['english', 'math', 'math', 3.5, 2.4, 3.9],
                            ['english', 'english', 'math', 3.5, 3.6, 3.9],
                            ['english', 'english', 'math', 3.7, 3.5, 3.8],
                            ], index=range(4), columns=columns)
print(students_df)

         major                 gpa          
       Joe      Bob  Sara  Joe  Bob Sara
0  english     math  math  3.8  2.2  3.7
1  english     math  math  3.5  2.4  3.9
2  english  english  math  3.5  3.6  3.9
3  english  english  math  3.7  3.5  3.8
```

Expected Output

```
       rank          
       Joe  Bob Sara
0      1      2    1
1      1      2    1
2      2      1    1
3      1      2    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stack` to setup the dataframe, so that you can effectively `groupby` the index ([0,1,2,3]) and `major` to calculate the `rank`. Then, `unstack(1)` the dataframe back into it's original column. The integer parameter passed to `stack()` indicates the position of the multi-index column level, that you send from columns to rows (or wide-to-long). And, `unstack()` is the exact opposite -- it sends from rows to columns (or long-to-wide). So, `0` is the first level, `1` is the second level, etc. Regardless of position, `stack()` and `unstack()` are very effective at unpivoting / pivoting dataframes.

Here is method 1 utilizing `.index.get_level_values(0)`:

```
df = students_df.stack(1)
df = (df.assign(gpa=df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0), 'major'])
                      .rank(ascending=False)).unstack(1))
        
Out[1]: 
   gpa              major               
   Bob  Joe Sara      Bob      Joe  Sara
0  2.0  1.0  1.0     math  english  math
1  2.0  1.0  1.0     math  english  math
2  1.0  2.0  1.0  english  english  math
3  2.0  1.0  1.0  english  english  math
```

---

Here is method 2 utilizing `rename_axis()` but has a slightly different output:

```
df = students_df.stack(1).rename_axis(['', 'Name'])
df = df.assign(gpa=df.groupby(['', 'major']).rank(ascending=False)).unstack(1)
df

Out[2]: 
      gpa              major               
Name  Bob  Joe Sara      Bob      Joe  Sara

0     2.0  1.0  1.0     math  english  math
1     2.0  1.0  1.0     math  english  math
2     1.0  2.0  1.0  english  english  math
3     2.0  1.0  1.0  english  english  math
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this monstrocity. It is correct but I hope someone offers a better solution:

```
ranks = students_df.stack().reset_index()\
                   .groupby(['level_0', 'major']).rank(ascending=False)
students_df.stack().reset_index().join(ranks, rsuffix='_rank')\
           .set_index(['level_0', 'level_1'])['gpa_rank'].unstack().astype(int)
#level_1  Bob  Joe  Sara
#level_0                
#0          2    1     1
#1          2    1     1
#2          1    2     1
#3          2    1     1
```